# Highstock yaxis title on "high left"

Tags: highcharts

I am making a Highstock chart using Highcharts, I need the title on the top left corner, just like Highcharts does.

[image]

In highcharts I can do it using yAxis.title.align: 'high', as you can see in this snippet

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {

    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'yAxis.title.offset is set to zero'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },

    yAxis: {
        lineWidth: 1,
        tickWidth: 1,
        title: {
            align: 'high',
            offset: 0,
            text: 'Rainfall (mm)',
            rotation: 0,
            y: -10
        }
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }]

});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
```

This doesn't work in a Highstock chart, using same options, as you can see on the following snippet:

[image]

```js
Highcharts.stockChart('container', {

    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'title offset is set to zero and align is high'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },

    yAxis: {
        lineWidth: 1,
        tickWidth: 1,
        top: "10%",
        height: "90%",
        title: {
            align: 'high',
            offset: 0,
            text: 'Rainfall (mm)',
            rotation: 0,
            y: -10
        }
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }]

});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
```

How can I aligne this text on the top-left side?

Comment: You need to set your yAxis as `opposite: true` to move where you want the yAxis labels/title to show. Highcharts defaults to left. Highstock defaults to right.

Comment: @wergeld it should be `opposite: false` instead of `opposite: true`: http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/L179u6qr/

Comment: opposite: false worked for me, thank you!